# Karate: json path element equals not working

Tags: karate

I have this feature:

```
Given path 'group/'
When method get
Then status 200
And match response.group[*].name contains [ 'group1' ] #Works
And match response.group[?(@.name == 'group1')].name contains [ 'group1' ] #Does not work
```

This is the response of `group/` endpoint:

```
{
  "group": [
    {
      "name": "group1",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "group2",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
groups.groups: groups.feature:35 - evaluation (js) failed: 'group1')].name contains [ 'group1' ], <eval>:1:8 Expected ; but found )
'group1')].name contains [ 'group1' ]
        ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 8
```

I checked the syntax in https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples and seems to be fine.

Thanks in advance.

EDITED: The non working expression is just an example to keep the question simple. Actually, I want to get the whole group from the list so I can compare other fields like `id` and use fuzzy matchers that I can't use with `contains`:

```
And match response.group[?(@.name == 'group1')][0] ==
"""
{
  "name": "group1",
  "id": #notnull
}
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a fault of the parser, the brackets on the LHS confuse it. But this is rare (and in this case super-contrived). Do two steps:

```
* def temp = $.group[?(@.name == 'group1')].name
* match temp contains [ 'group1' ]
```

Feel free to submit a PR against the docs or the code, thanks ;)

Comment: I edited the question to show my real problem (answer is still valid). I was trying to retrieve an element of the list so I can use fuzzy matchers because they are not supported by the contains operator. The workaround was fine (note: if I use 'response' instead of '$' the expression stops working).

Comment: @italktothewind note: read the docs https://github.com/intuit/karate#get-short-cut

Comment: I got it, 'response' only works when it is used with match operator.

Comment: @italktothewind nope. response will work if it is JS and not JsonPath, e.g. `response.foo[0]` will work